# Can I get the command line information of running browser using Javascript directly or indirectly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can I get the **command line** information of running browser using **Javascript** directly or indirectly?

For example - the information below:

Command Line "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks this is possible since browsers run your JS code in sandboxed environment. Here is a list of what you can do with Javascript in browser
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API